# coil resistance

Tags: resistance, coil

When I measure the coil resistance using a Simpson 360 meter, it reads 1 ohm.  When I use a GR digital bridge to measure it, it reads 2.5 ohms alon with an inductance of 3.5mH.  Why the difference in ohms?

Comment: My old Simpson is 20KOhms/V or 50uA full scale so you must be measuring the current shunt.  GR bridge calibration errors?

Comment: What are the relevant accuracy specifications for both instruments?

Comment: Measuring such low resistances without a four wire setup is just tossing numbers

Comment: Relevant accuracy?  Certainly not +/-200%.

Answer (score 1):

The inductance meters use inphase and quadrature voltage measurements. At some frequency.

Skin effect at the test frequency will explain the extra 1.5 ohms.

Comment: Skin effect only manifests at very frequencies.  This is measured at 60Hz.  What frequency are you referring to when you say "some frequency"?

Comment: In copper, 60Hz skin depth is 8cm. In copper, 60MHz skin depth is down by 1/sqrt(1,000,000) or 1/1,000. With 8cm being 80milliMeters, the 60MHz SD is 0.08 milliMeters, or 8 microns, or 1/4 the thickness of standard copper foil.

Comment: ahhhemmmm All those depths are 10X too big. SD of 60Hz is 0.8cm. At 60MHz, SD is indeed 1,000X smaller, at 0.008 millimeters or 8 microns.

Comment: I've settled at 4MHz as the frequency where standard copper foil, 35 micron thick (1.4mils) is one SkinDepth thick, as I try to think about magnetic shielding. Thus 60MHz, approx. 16X faster, would have 4X thinner SD. And 35/4 ~~ 8 microns. Trying to internalize these effects.